# CLLocationManager in iOS9 giving incorrect locations (iOS8 is OK)

Tags: cllocationmanager, ios9

We experience some weird issues on the locations from CCLocationManager starting from iOS9. iOS 7-8 has no issues. The weird locations cause errors in the app. The app is used while driving a car and we have about 50 test users in TestFlight and some of them are reporting these issues.

The app reacts on location updates, each location update, each 25m and each 50m there is something to do. For test I've stored all these locations in an array. Our test users have a button which will send the history in GPX format to me by mail.

For example the following 12 locations where send to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" creator="flitsmeister-ios-app-test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
  <wpt lat="51.28165091" lon="5.77329012">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:55.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:55.460</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.5</course>
    <speed>13.3</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.1</altitude>
    <sequencenr>0</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28138654" lon="5.77244497">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:55.506</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:55.523</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>69.3</course>
    <speed>13.5</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.7</altitude>
    <sequencenr>1</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28171319" lon="5.77345935">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:56.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:56.441</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.2</course>
    <speed>13.2</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.0</altitude>
    <sequencenr>2</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28138654" lon="5.77244497">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:56.562</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:56.571</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>69.3</course>
    <speed>13.5</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.7</altitude>
    <sequencenr>3</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28177064" lon="5.77362548">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:57.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:57.440</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>60.1</course>
    <speed>13.4</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>32.9</altitude>
    <sequencenr>4</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28138654" lon="5.77244497">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:57.541</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:57.558</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>69.3</course>
    <speed>13.5</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.7</altitude>
    <sequencenr>5</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28182383" lon="5.77380183">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:58.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:58.438</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.2</course>
    <speed>13.7</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.3</altitude>
    <sequencenr>6</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28138654" lon="5.77244497">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:58.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:58.491</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>69.3</course>
    <speed>13.5</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.7</altitude>
    <sequencenr>7</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28188803" lon="5.77398322">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:36:59.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:36:59.431</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.5</course>
    <speed>14.4</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.4</altitude>
    <sequencenr>8</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28202386" lon="5.77435235">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:37:01.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:37:01.432</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.2</course>
    <speed>14.9</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.5</altitude>
    <sequencenr>9</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28188803" lon="5.77398322">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:37:01.444</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:37:01.454</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.5</course>
    <speed>14.4</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.4</altitude>
    <sequencenr>10</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28208027" lon="5.77454128">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:37:02.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:37:02.430</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.9</course>
    <speed>15.1</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.3</altitude>
    <sequencenr>11</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28188803" lon="5.77398322">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:37:02.513</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:37:02.521</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.5</course>
    <speed>14.4</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.4</altitude>
    <sequencenr>12</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="51.28217918" lon="5.77472677">
    <datetimegps>2015-09-29T04:37:03.371</datetimegps>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-09-29T04:37:03.434</datetimeprocessed>
    <course>61.5</course>
    <speed>15.2</speed>
    <accuracyhorizontal>5.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>3.0</accuracyvertical>
    <altitude>33.5</altitude>
    <sequencenr>13</sequencenr>
  </wpt>
</gpx>
```

If I print these location on a map (geoplaner.com is my friend), I will see this:

[image: Points printed on the map]

Remark: Points B D F H are on the same location, but for the illustration of the problem I have put those on 1 row next to each other.

As you can see if you follow the sequence A,B,C you will see that point B is not on the right location.

Starting from iOS9 build almost every test user has experienced this situation once or two times in a week.

Following some code we use:

CLLocationManager (on the mean thread):

```
_manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_manager.delegate = self;
_manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
_manager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
_manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = TRUE;

if([_manager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)])
    _manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = TRUE;
[_manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

In another method I call the start (also when app starts and stop it when it terminates). (main thread)

```
[_manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Code for working with Locations (I've removed some code to keep the example clean):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *lastLocation = [locations lastObject];

    // test that the horizontal accuracy does not indicate an invalid measurement
    if (lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;
    
    // test the age of the location measurement to determine if the measurement is cached
    // in most cases you will not want to rely on cached measurements
    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[lastLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge > 5.0)
        return;

    NSDate *dateLocationArrived = [NSDate date];
    
    CLLocation *beforeLocationRealtime = [self.LastLocationRealtime copy];
    CLLocation *newLocation = [lastLocation copy];


    //Realtime location.
    [self setSpeedForLocation:[newLocation copy] withOldRealtimeLocation:[beforeLocationRealtime copy]];
    
    [_delegateKaart updatedRealtimeLocation:newLocation fromPreviousLocation:[self.PreviousCurrentLocation copy]];
    
    self.BeforeLastLocationRealtime = [self.LastLocationRealtime copy];
    self.LastLocationRealtime = [newLocation copy];

    if([self.CurrentLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation] < 50) //Less then 50m?
    {
        if([_locationEach25m distanceFromLocation:newLocation] > 25)
        {
            //Nieuwe last 25m.
            _locationEach25m = [newLocation copy];
            
   
            //Each 25m do
            [_delegateDashboard updatedLocation:[newLocation copy]];
            [_delegateSignalering locationUpdated:[newLocation copy]];
            
            [self holdLast200LocationsAndAddLocation:[lastLocation copy] withLocationArray:locations AndArriveDate:dateLocationArrived AndVerwerkt:TRUE];
        }
        else
            [self holdLast200LocationsAndAddLocation:[lastLocation copy] withLocationArray:locations AndArriveDate:dateLocationArrived AndVerwerkt:FALSE];
        return;//Stop
    }

    //Each 50m 
    [self holdLast200LocationsAndAddLocation:[lastLocation copy] withLocationArray:locations AndArriveDate:dateLocationArrived AndVerwerkt:TRUE];

    _locationEach25m = [newLocation copy]; //Also new last 25m .
    self.PreviousCurrentLocation = [self.CurrentLocation copy];//50m back. 
    self.CurrentLocation = [newLocation copy]; 
    
    [_delegateDashboard updatedLocation:[newLocation copy]];
    [_delegateSignalering locationUpdated:[newLocation copy]];
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [_delegateCountryDetector locationUpdated:[newLocation copy]];
        [self setHuidigeWegForLocation:[newLocation copy]];
    });
    
    [[SignaleringController sharedInstance] runSignaleringCheckForLocation:[newLocation copy]];
}
```

It feels like an iOS9 bug in the locationmanager which is giving me incorrect results on the whereabouts of the user. If I search Stackoverflow.com it seems Im the only one.

## --> Example2:

```
  <wpt lat="52.32835728" lon="5.05861943">
    <datetimegps>2015-10-01T06:27:29.905</datetimegps>
    <datetimearrivedincode>2015-10-01T06:27:30.196</datetimearrivedincode>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-10-01T06:27:30.205</datetimeprocessed>
    <c>138.4</c>
    <s>26.5</s>
    <accuracyhorizontal>10.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>6.0</accuracyvertical>
    <al>5.9</al>
    <nr>95</nr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="52.32813366" lon="5.05927501">
    <datetimegps>2015-10-01T06:27:31.905</datetimegps>
    <datetimearrivedincode>2015-10-01T06:27:32.275</datetimearrivedincode>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-10-01T06:27:32.301</datetimeprocessed>
    <c>119.5</c>
    <s>26.0</s>
    <accuracyhorizontal>10.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>4.0</accuracyvertical>
    <al>5.7</al>
    <nr>96</nr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="52.32835728" lon="5.05861943">
    <datetimegps>2015-10-01T06:27:33.196</datetimegps>
    <datetimearrivedincode>2015-10-01T06:27:33.203</datetimearrivedincode>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-10-01T06:27:33.275</datetimeprocessed>
    <c>138.4</c>
    <s>26.5</s>
    <accuracyhorizontal>10.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>6.0</accuracyvertical>
    <al>5.9</al>
    <nr>97</nr>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="52.32802075" lon="5.05960610">
    <datetimegps>2015-10-01T06:27:32.905</datetimegps>
    <datetimearrivedincode>2015-10-01T06:27:33.246</datetimearrivedincode>
    <datetimeprocessed>2015-10-01T06:27:33.283</datetimeprocessed>
    <c>119.2</c>
    <s>26.3</s>
    <accuracyhorizontal>10.0</accuracyhorizontal>
    <accuracyvertical>4.0</accuracyvertical>
    <al>5.3</al>
    <nr>98</nr>
  </wpt>
```

On the map:

[image: second example]

Note: A and C are on the exact location, I changed them manually to show A is behind C.

The following is weird:

1. 4rd/D has an earlier GPS time then point 3rd/C
2. Somehow I didnt get a location for 06:27:31 but got two 06:27:33
3. 1st/A and 3rd/C have the same GPS coordinates. This can't be correct because the car is driving the highway 26m/s (93km/h).

Point 3 means I cant just fix it by holding the last GPS date and skip everything earlier then the last one.

## --> Example 3:

Total GPX file:
[image: Total GPX file]

Zoomed-in at the problem:
[image: Zoomed-in at the problem]

Moved the double and incorrect order points next to each other:
[image: Moved the double and incorrect order points next to each other]

Just reloaded the points im interested in with ABCD notations.
[image: Just reloaded the points im interested in with ABCD notations]

The GPX file from the above screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" creator="flitsmeister-ios-app-test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<wpt lat="51.89792674" lon="4.54830456">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:40.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:23:53.850</tv>
  <c>131.8</c>
  <s>13.1</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>3.0</av>
  <al>2.0</al>
  <nr>464</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89745789" lon="4.54927853">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:47.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:23:53.910</tv>
  <c>125.9</c>
  <s>8.6</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>6.0</av>
  <al>5.4</al>
  <nr>465</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89745789" lon="4.54927853">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:47.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:23:53.929</tv>
  <c>125.9</c>
  <s>8.6</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>6.0</av>
  <al>5.4</al>
  <nr>466</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89745789" lon="4.54927853">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:47.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:23:53.932</tv>
  <c>125.9</c>
  <s>8.6</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>6.0</av>
  <al>5.4</al>
  <nr>467</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89762654" lon="4.54890185">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:44.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:23:53.933</tv>
  <c>128.0</c>
  <s>13.4</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>4.0</av>
  <al>0.6</al>
  <nr>468</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89745789" lon="4.54927853">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:47.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:23:53.965</tv>
  <c>125.9</c>
  <s>8.6</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>6.0</av>
  <al>5.4</al>
  <nr>469</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89755810" lon="4.54904694">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:45.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:24:02.016</tv>
  <c>126.9</c>
  <s>12.5</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>4.0</av>
  <al>0.2</al>
  <nr>470</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89800163" lon="4.54815385">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:47.731</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:24:02.068</tv>
  <c>132.9</c>
  <s>12.8</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>4.0</av>
  <al>2.3</al>
  <nr>471</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89800163" lon="4.54815385">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:47.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:24:05.832</tv>
  <c>132.9</c>
  <s>12.8</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>4.0</av>
  <al>2.3</al>
  <nr>472</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89749909" lon="4.54917803">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:46.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:24:05.842</tv>
  <c>126.9</c>
  <s>10.8</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>4.0</av>
  <al>8.4</al>
  <nr>473</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89800163" lon="4.54815385">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:47.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:24:06.289</tv>
  <c>132.9</c>
  <s>12.8</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>4.0</av>
  <al>2.3</al>
  <nr>474</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89745789" lon="4.54927853">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:47.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:24:06.307</tv>
  <c>125.9</c>
  <s>8.6</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>6.0</av>
  <al>5.4</al>
  <nr>475</nr>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="51.89732735" lon="4.54958171">
  <tgps>2015-09-29T15:23:52.999</tgps>
  <tv>2015-09-29T15:24:06.339</tv>
  <c>121.6</c>
  <s>2.9</s>
  <ah>5.0</ah>
  <av>4.0</av>
  <al>-2.3</al>
  <nr>476</nr>
</wpt>
  </gpx>
```

In this file the problem occurred a couple times but seems to locate at 2 problem locations. After that no problems more but the user killed the app after a some KM.

## --> I've tried:

1. Setting ActivityType to CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation
2. Setting pauseLocationUpdatesAuto to YES
3. DesiredAccuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
4. Moving everything to the main thread and don't do any thread changing.
5. Extending the logging to see if my array Locations contains more then one locationobject, but this isn't the case.
6. Logging the HASH and Pointer location, but they are all differently.

## --> I've learned:

1. Don't set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to FALSE. It's default TRUE and for a navigation app it should stay TRUE. You will get a lot more locations when you set this to FALSE, locations that are no different to another one.
2. Set properties on the CLLocationManager once, when you change properties to often weird and more locations will arrive at the delegate. In example: if you set these properties in the delegate method didUpdateLocation you will end up with 4 locations on the exact same millisecond.

   _manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
   _manager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;

Comment: At any point in your code are you reducing accuracy?

Comment: Only point is when I initialise the locationmanager: _manager.desiredAccuracy

Comment: Have you found any tests where this occurs for different users (or different tests with the same user) in the same geographical area?  Perhaps a stretch of highway that has caused the issue for multiple users?

Comment: This occurs on different Roads in the Netherlands, so different locations. We have 50 active testflight users and at least 10 of them reported this issue. It's hard to find a reproduction situation so I can drive with my laptop to debug easier.

Comment: @Sjoerd Perfors can you please show final code? thx

Comment: Sorry can't do, problem was one year ago and I don't have a sample project (anymore).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The following things where wrong:

1. I had another CLLocationManager in my project running this code each second:

   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)]) {
       locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = TRUE;
   }
2. I was setting properties on the CLLocationManager more than once. When you change properties too often, weird and extra locations will arrive at the delegate. For example: if you set these properties in the delegate method `didUpdateLocation` you will end up with 4 locations on the exact same millisecond.

   _manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
   _manager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
3. We have found out that one test user had his GPS chip broken or something. For some reason his device reported wrong GPS coordinates occasionally. Make sure at least two users are reporting an error! At some point when we fixed point 1 and 2, this user had this error but all other users were OK. Later on he also reported errors with the store version (which was build with iOS8).
4. Don't disable `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` (set it to false). It defaults to enabled and for a navigation app it should stay enabled. You will get a lot more locations when you disable this, locations that are no different to another one.

So yes, there is a big difference between iOS8 and iOS9. If you experience weird locations check these points above.

Comment: Sorry can't do, problem was one year ago and I don't have a sample project (anymore).

Comment: Here is the code if you need it `locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
        locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.automotiveNavigation
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is the entire story, but after investigating for 2 days here's what I think is going on.

The locationManager will do something like what you're describing (duplicate locations) if it's recreated at any point.  This makes sense in a way, if you make a new locationManager or re-initialize your current one it will receive another set of your current location.  I was able to get similar results by creating a toy app that recreated the locationManager every time a button was pressed and clicking the button regularly.

If the locationManager loses network connection  (cell signal and wifi) it's unable to transmit the position data.  In short I believe the locationManager is being destroyed  whenever the device loses internet connection and when it's recreated moments later it's using the old coordinates.  Why it's caching these values and how the time signatures are incorrect is still a mystery to me.

Finally I created a [toy app](https://github.com/Aabglov/Breadcrumb) that uses the same code you use to initialize it's locationManager (minus the code used to store the previous 200 locations).  All it does is put a pin on the map every time it receives your location.  I drove around with it and did see inconsistent placements, but not exactly what you described.  The fact that I did see odd behavior leads me to assume this is a bug with iOS 9 and not your code.

At this point, considering all the other bugs found in iOS 9 so far, I think it's fair to chalk this one up to Apple.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this, I finally figured it out and due to bad GPS chip of one user this misleaded me on finding the solution. I reproduced the error with point1 from my Answer (calling another CLLocationManager each second).

Answer (score 0):

can't add comment..

still only work fine by setting distanceFilter

I follow your answer:
`_locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;
  _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;`

also find some wired locations like this:[image]

first is completely equal the third,
why is that ...

Comment: Can you perhaps adjust your own question with some code examples ? Also make sure any other CLLocationManagers aren't running.

Comment: hi, I'm sure there's only one CLLocationManager,  I post another question:[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147568/weird-locations-from-cllocationmanager-in-ios9), help me out ,thanks!