# Weird locations from CLLocationManager in iOS9

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

I have developed a walk app that can record distance, on iOS7, iOS8, the distance is mostly fine although sometimes not accurate, but on iOS9.0, the distance often too large, so I check

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)
```

Locations method, and find some time get locations like this: A、B、C,  but coordinate of C is equal to A, which i think is weird

I find `startUpdatingLocation` called every seconds, after get rid of it , it gets better, but still happens

here is the demo [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3yyqoogpsk3apx5/GpsTestSingle.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Have you done this code for ios 9. allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates

Comment: what accurate distance did u set?

Comment: @vijay yes  I have done

Comment: @ dimpiax  kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation and kCLDistanceFilterNone

Comment: Okie..Great.. using this allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates?

Comment: @vijay I have set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to YES

Comment: Okie. its userfull than vote to my ans

Answer (score 0):

For ios 9, you have to set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates.